# when we should use AddSingleTon and when AddScoped and When should use AddTransient

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Could please Give RealTime Example when we should use AddSingleTon and when AddScoped and When should use AddTransient.

Comment: This isn't a good question for stackoverflow. There are plenty of articles and documentation on this subject https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#lifetime-and-registration-options

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Singleton is normally used for a global single instance. For example, you will have an image store service you could have a service to load images from a given location and keeps them in memory for future use.

A scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request. Normally we will use this for sql connection. It means it will create and dispose the sql connection per request.

A transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container. For example, during one request you use httpclient service to call other web api request multiple times, but the web api endpoint is different. At that time you will register the httpclient service as transient. That means each time when you call the httpclient service it will create a new httpclient to send the request not used the same one .

Answer (score 1):

Transient — Services are created each time they are requested. It gets a new instance of the injected object, on each request of this object. For each time you inject this object is injected in the class, it will create a new instance.

Scoped — Services are created on each request (once per request). This is most recommended for WEB applications. So for example, if during a request you use the same dependency injection, in many places, you will use the same instance of that object, it will make reference to the same memory allocation.

Singleton — Services are created once for the lifetime of the application. It uses the same instance for the whole application.

Comment: Did you even read the question? "When to use" and its not "What is the definition"